# Spark-cassandra-connector: toArray does not work

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using the spark-cassandra-connector with Scala and I want to read data from cassandra and display it via the method toArray.
However, I get an error message that it is not member of a class, but it is indicated in the API. Could somebody help me in finding my error?

Here are my files:

build.sbt:

```
name := "Simple_Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
 case PathList("META-INF", xs @ _*) => MergeStrategy.discard
 case x => MergeStrategy.first
}

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.0-preview"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.0-preview"
resolvers += "Spark Packages Repo" at "https://dl.bintray.com/spark-packages/maven"
libraryDependencies += "datastax" % "spark-cassandra-connector" % "2.0.0-M2-s_2.11"
```

SimpleScala.scala:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd._
import org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import com.datastax.spark.connector.cql.CassandraConnector._

object SimpleApp {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Simple Application")
    conf.set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", "127.0.0.1")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val rdd_2 = sc.cassandraTable("test_2", "words")

    rdd_2.toArray.foreach(println)
   }
 }
```

Functions for cqlsh:

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test_2 WITH REPLICATION = {'class': 'SimpleStrategy', 'replication_factor': 1 };

CREATE TABLE test_2.words (word text PRIMARY KEY, count int);
INSERT INTO test_2.words (word, count) VALUES ('foo', 20);
INSERT INTO test_2.words (word, count) VALUES ('bar', 20);
```

Error message:

```
[info] Loading global plugins from /home/andi/.sbt/0.13/plugins
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cc8d2761242b072cedb0a04cb39435[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Loading project definition from /home/andi/test_spark/project
[info] Updating {file:/home/andi/test_spark/project/}test_spark-build...
[info] Resolving org.scala-sbt.ivy#ivy;2.3.0-sbt-2cc8d2761242b072cedb0a04cb39435[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[info] Set current project to Simple_Project (in build file:/home/andi/test_spark/)
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /home/andi/test_spark/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[error] /home/andi/test_spark/src/main/scala/SimpleApp.scala:50: value toArray is not a member of com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD[com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow]
[error] rdd_2.toArray.foreach(println)
[error]       ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed
```

Many thanks in advance, 
Andi

Answer (score 3):

CassandraTableScanRDD.toArray method has been deprecated and removed since [2.0.0](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/2.0.0/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD) release of Spark Cassandra Connector. This method was there until [1.6.0](http://datastax.github.io/spark-cassandra-connector/ApiDocs/1.6.0/spark-cassandra-connector/#com.datastax.spark.connector.rdd.CassandraTableScanRDD) release. You can use collect method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the document [Spark Cassandra Connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md) still uses toArray. Anyway, here is that will work

```
rdd_2.collect.foreach(println)
```